# RecyclerView not scrolling in Collapsing Toolbar

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, coordinator-layout

I have a very simple RecyclerView inside a Collapsing Toolbar layout. I have tried every possible flag / researched everywhere I could but cannot get my collapsing toolbar to collapse. The Recycler scrolls freely, but the collapsingtoolbar just stays there, unless, I scroll the collapsingtoolbar itself. What am I doing wrong, can anyone please help? Any help will be much much appreciated..

XML as follows (Just to keep the code clean, have removed the section within the Relative Layout of the Collapsing toolbar):

```
<!-- The CoordinatorLayout is used to coordinate (rly) scroll events between different views -->
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- The AppBar (everything above the scrolling content) -->
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main__app_bar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">



<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main__collapsing_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:contentScrim="@color/dark_for_menu"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/coverSwappsterMode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </RelativeLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" >


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>




            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/listSwappsterMode"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/dp_500"
                android:background="@color/dark_background"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                >
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>





</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I think your problem is `wrap_content` for the toolbar content height.

Comment: Do you mean the "wrap_content" in the <RelativeLayout> that is the first child of <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout? Could you suggest what it should be instead, if not wrap_content?

Comment: just try using `40dp` or something :)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nopes, nothing worked. Finally I just created a gridview, where the first row was the header and mimiced the behavior of collapsing tool bar based on the % visibility of the first row. Unfortunately I can't find the code now. If I am able to, will post it for sure.

Answer (score 1):

you need to put your page layout inside a "nested scroll view"

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

wrapping the recyclerview should do it.